# Randomly generate trees for unit testing

Tags: c#

I want to randomly generate trees (not BST) for unit testing of my code. I have tried it in a number of ways but somehow after generation of 3 -4 trees there is an exception or code goes into infinite loop. I am using random numbers for edges and node values.
I have also tried queue approach where I fill up the queue with random numbers and then dequeue nodes and randomly select the old node from the existing items in the queue and then connect this new node.

Does anybody know how to do this in C# in more better and succinct way?

EDIT

```
public class Tree
{
    public Node Root { get; private set; }
    public readonly Dictionary<long, Node> Nodes = new Dictionary<long, Node>();
    public readonly Dictionary<string, long> SumDictionary = new Dictionary<string, long>();

    public readonly Dictionary<long, long> FDictionary = new Dictionary<long, long>
    {
        {0, 1},
        {1, 1}
    };


    public long Query(long n)
    {
        long s = 0;
        Dfs();

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i; j <= n; j++)
            {
                var lvalue = GetLValue(i, j);

                if (i != j)
                {
                    lvalue *= 2;
                }

                s += lvalue;

                if (s >= Mod)
                {
                    s %= Mod;
                }

            }
        }

        return s;
    }

    private long GetLValue(int a, int b)
    {
        var key = string.Format("{0}-{1}", a, b);

        if (SumDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            return Fvalue(SumDictionary[key]);
        }

        var aKey = string.Format("{0}-{1}", 1, a);
        var bKey = string.Format("{0}-{1}", 1, b);

        var sumA = SumDictionary[aKey];
        var sumB = SumDictionary[bKey];

        var lca = Lca(a, b);

        if (lca != a && lca != b)
        {
            return Fvalue(sumA + sumB - SumDictionary[string.Format("{0}-{1}", lca, lca)]);
        }


        long bigSum, smallSum;

        if (sumA > sumB)
        {
            bigSum = sumA;
            smallSum = sumB;
        }
        else
        {
            bigSum = sumB;
            smallSum = sumA;
        }

        var sumAtoB = bigSum - (smallSum - Nodes[smallSum].Value);

        return Fvalue(sumAtoB);
    }

    public void AddNode(long a, long b)
    {
        Node nodea, nodeb;
        if (Nodes.ContainsKey(a))
        {
            nodea = Nodes[a];
        }
        else
        {
            nodea = new Node { Value = a };
            Nodes.Add(a, nodea);
        }

        if (Nodes.ContainsKey(b))
        {
            nodeb = Nodes[b];
        }
        else
        {
            nodeb = new Node { Value = b };
            Nodes.Add(b, nodeb);
        }

        nodea.ReachableNodes.Add(b, nodeb);
        nodeb.ReachableNodes.Add(a, nodea);

        if (Root == null)
        {
            Root = nodea;
        }
    }

    public long? Lca(int a, int b)
    {
        bool found = false;
        return TraverseForLca(Root, null, a, b, ref found);
    }

    private long? TraverseForLca(Node node, Node prev, long a, long b, ref bool found)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (node.Value == a)
        {
            return a;
        }

        if (node.Value == b)
        {
            return b;
        }


        long? f = null;

        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Node> reachableNode in node.ReachableNodes)
        {
            var n = reachableNode.Value;

            if (prev != null && n.Value == prev.Value)
            {
                continue;
            }

            long? lca = TraverseForLca(n, node, a, b, ref found);

            if (found)
            {
                return lca;
            }

            if (lca != null && f == null)
            {
                f = lca;
            }
            else if (lca != null)
            {
                found = true;
                return node.Value;
            }
        }

        return f;
    }

    public void Dfs()
    {
        TravelForDfs(Root, null, 0);
    }

    private void TravelForDfs(Node node, Node prev, long recSum)
    {
        if (node == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var key = string.Format("{0}-{1}", prev != null ? prev.Value : node.Value, node.Value);
        var iKey = string.Format("{0}-{1}", node.Value, node.Value);
        var weight = node.Weight;

        if (weight >= Mod)
        {
            weight %= Mod;
        }


        if (!SumDictionary.ContainsKey(iKey))
        {
            SumDictionary.Add(iKey, weight);
        }

        weight = recSum + node.Weight;

        if (weight >= Mod)
        {
            weight %= Mod;
        }

        foreach (KeyValuePair<long, Node> reachableNode in node.ReachableNodes)
        {
            var n = reachableNode.Value;

            if (prev != null && n.Value == prev.Value)
            {
                if (!SumDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
                {
                    SumDictionary.Add(key, weight);
                }

                continue;
            }

            if (!SumDictionary.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                SumDictionary.Add(key, weight);
            }

            TravelForDfs(n, node, weight);
        }
    }

    public long Fvalue(long n)
    {
        if (n == 1 || n == 0)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        long a, b;

        if (FDictionary.ContainsKey(n - 1))
        {
            a = FDictionary[n - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            a = Fvalue(n - 1);

            if (!FDictionary.ContainsKey(n - 1))
            {
                FDictionary.Add(n - 1, a);
            }

        }

        if (FDictionary.ContainsKey(n - 2))
        {
            b = FDictionary[n - 2];
        }
        else
        {
            b = Fvalue(n - 2);

            if (!FDictionary.ContainsKey(n - 2))
            {
                FDictionary.Add(n - 2, b);
            }

        }


        if (!FDictionary.ContainsKey(n))
        {
            FDictionary.Add(n, a + b);
        }


        var s = a + b;
        if (s >= Mod)
        {
            s %= Mod;
        }

        return s;

    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code of your tree and an example of what you want

Comment: I don't want random tree generation function to depend on the question. It should just generate a tree. Just like an array of random numbers. Totally independent of the problem. Anyhow, I have posted my tree code.

Comment: Please explain the logic of `AddNode` method, why it accepts two parameters and why do you need `Dictionary<long, Node>`

Comment: So this a problem that is asked in HackerRank. Since the contest is going on I can't share the question as it will violate the rules. The input given in the question is of form a b which means there is a connection between node a and node b. for ex 1 3 means that node 1 and node 3 are connected and so no. The Dictionary is used keep track of children nodes since there is no concept of left and right nodes here. So one node can have multiple childrens

Comment: Unit tests should almost never be "random". If a test fails in one condition but not in another randomly generated condition, it's a pretty bad test because it's not reproducible

Comment: I have noticed that in .NET that random number generation is always the same between multiple runs of the unit tests if the seed value is not changed. So it is always reproducible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It should just generate a tree

Does this tree meet your requirements?

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public List<TreeNode<T>> Childs { get; }

    public TreeNode()
    {
        Childs = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    }
}

public class TreeGenerator
{
    private readonly int maxChilds;
    private readonly Random rnd = new Random();

    public TreeGenerator(int maxChilds)
    {
        this.maxChilds = maxChilds;
    }

    public TreeNode<T> CreateTree<T>(int maxDepth, Func<T> valueGenerator)
    {
        var node = new TreeNode<T>();
        node.Value = valueGenerator();
        if (maxDepth > 0)
        {
            var childsCount = rnd.Next(maxChilds);
            for (var i = 0; i < childsCount; ++i)
                node.Childs.Add(CreateTree(maxDepth - 1, valueGenerator));
        }
        return node;
    }

    public static void Demo()
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var generator = new TreeGenerator(3 /* max childs count*/);
        var tree = generator.CreateTree(4 /*max depth*/, () => rnd.Next() /*node value*/);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks a lot